# Deploying WCF services in a production environment

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

The web provides an abundance of tutorials for developing and testing WCF services along with client applications that reference them all within the Visual Studio IDE.

However, in a production setting, one needs to deploy services and clients on various hosts where Visual Studio is not available, and the clients need to be configured to know the URL of the whatever service they expect to use.

Can anyone provide some instructions for this kind of deployment, or link me to a web page that contains the information that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you will know when you launch your client where the services will be you can define all of the configuration in your app/web.config file. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx) should help get you started

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the URL needed by a client in a configuration file and have that loaded on startup.  That will allow you to easily change which URL is used by any client.